# How can I disable the automatic gray selection in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using a `WKWebView` in my application. When I tap on something, a gray colored overlay appears on the view, as shown in the image:

[image: Example of the gray overlay after selection]

I have already disabled back-forward navigation. Disabling user interaction is not an option for me, since I want to preserve the ability of clicking on links.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable that using the CSS property `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let wv = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(wv)
        wv.load(URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let script = "function addStyleString(str) {" +
                "var node = document.createElement('style');" +
                "node.innerHTML = str;" +
                "document.body.appendChild(node);" +
            "}" +
            "addStyleString('* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}');"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue! Unfortunately, this has a small side effect: the in-site links' selection rectangles are also gone. This is not an issue for me but it could be for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous answer but slightly shorter, you can put transparent color instead.

```swift
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.webkitTapHighlightColor='transparent';")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others!